# How to go through JSON product like it is your database?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, stringify

I have a JSON file which looks like this:

```
{
  "COMPONENTS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "Components.xls",
  "CONTRACT_DETAILS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "ContractDetails.xls",
  "CONTRACT_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "Contracts.xls",
  "EQUIPMENTS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "EquipmentList.xls",
  "FILENAME_PDF_SERVICE_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" : "ServicePerformanceReport.pdf",
  "INVOICES_CONTRACT_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "ContractInvoices.xls",
  "INVOICES_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "ServiceInvoice.xls",
  "INVOICES_PSR_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "PSR_Invoices.xls",
  "MG_REQUEST_TYPE_OPTION_VALUES" : "PMReq:#Preventive Maintenance" 
  "OPTIONS_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "OptionsList.xls"
}
```

I want to create a search bar where if I type : xls

It should return me:

```
OPTIONS_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME: OptionsList.xls
COMPONENTS_EXPORT_FILENAME : Components.xls
CONTRACT_DETAILS_EXPORT_FILENAME : ContractDetails.xls
CONTRACT_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME : Contracts.xls
EQUIPMENTS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : EquipmentList.xls
```

and so on

I am using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`

but I have to use specific name like `json_file.CONTRACT_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME`

and it gives me `contracts.xls`

Please suggest a workaround.

After the comments from @nikhil I came up with this code:

```
    var data = {
   "COMPONENTS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "Components.xls",
   "CONTRACT_DETAILS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "ContractDetails.xls",
   "CONTRACT_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "Contracts.xls",
   "EQUIPMENTS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "EquipmentList.xls",
  "FILENAME_PDF_SERVICE_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" : 
  "ServicePerformanceReport.pdf",
 "INVOICES_CONTRACT_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "ContractInvoices.xls",
 "INVOICES_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "ServiceInvoice.xls",
 "INVOICES_PSR_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "PSR_Invoices.xls",
 "MG_REQUEST_TYPE_OPTION_VALUES" : "PMReq:#Preventive Maintenance",
 "OPTIONS_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "OptionsList.xls"
 };


function getTextInput() {
        var e = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = e;
        return e;
        }

function search(data, searchKey) {
var results = [];

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (key.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase()) ||
  value.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase())) {
  results.push({
    [key]: [value]
  });
 }
});

 for(var i in results)
{
  document.write(i + "=" + results[i] + '<br>');
}


}
   search(data,getTextInput);
```

Comment: Do you want it to only find file extensions, or any arbitrary string? Do you want it to search the values, keys, or both?

Comment: There is 8 `.xls` in the json. Why should it return only 5 ?

Comment: Can you tell or show us what have you done so far?

Comment: @Cid Yes I meant it should return all 8

Comment: @JaredSmith any arbitary string should work

Comment: @JaredSmith yes I want to search for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to only return entries which include given search string.

```js
var data = {
  "COMPONENTS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "Components.xls",
  "CONTRACT_DETAILS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "ContractDetails.xls",
  "CONTRACT_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "Contracts.xls",
  "EQUIPMENTS_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "EquipmentList.xls",
  "FILENAME_PDF_SERVICE_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" : "ServicePerformanceReport.pdf",
  "INVOICES_CONTRACT_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "ContractInvoices.xls",
  "INVOICES_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "ServiceInvoice.xls",
  "INVOICES_PSR_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "PSR_Invoices.xls",
  "MG_REQUEST_TYPE_OPTION_VALUES" : "PMReq:#Preventive Maintenance",
  "OPTIONS_LIST_EXPORT_FILENAME" : "OptionsList.xls"
};


function search(data, searchKey) {
  return Object.entries(data).filter(([key, value]) => {
    return key.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase()) ||
      value.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase());
  });
}

console.log(search(data, ".xls"));
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I want to dynamically pass data and I am trying to do it with the getTextInput() function. I call this function in the input text wiith  "onchange = getTextInput()" and then I have a button called search which has "onclick = "search()" I am very new at this. Sorry for the silly qns. Still not getting the results printed on my webpage.

Comment: Then call `search(data, getTextInput())`  in onclick's `search()` function.

Comment: thanks a lot again! It did help :). Although I have one more small question, I am trying to get the output on the same screen, but with document.write(i + "=" + results[i] + '<br>'); it is not possible and with inner.html I am not understanding how to display the keyed array results []. Can you help me with it?

Comment: You're welcome @grushaanandpara. Take a look at this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dqghqr). You can do something like that where results are appended to a variable and displayed on the page at the end of the loop.